How to display the contents of my ASP.NET custom module created inside orchard CMS?
I am new to ASP.NET and orchard CMS and trying to integrate my ASP.NET project with orchard. I have got an ASP.NET custom module created inside my Orchard CMS by following the steps provided over here. I can see the contents of this module when I go to the custom module route (/helloWorld). But how do I convert this custom module to an orchard content  like the default 'Welcome to Orchard' content with view and editing features.
I tried creating a content from Ochard CMS > Content  > Create New Content but i figured out this was actually creating a new content through orchard and not taking my custom module code.
